# MasterPage error in different directory

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have asp.net project which have a `masterpage` file, when using this in any `newpage` in `same directory` its working, but if I make a different directory page then the style is not working good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got a relative reference to your CSS files that works from the master page folder, but not from other folders. That reference will always be resolved relative to the content page and not the master page.

For example, if your CSS is linked thus:

```
<link href="css/Style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

This will only work from content pages (note that the master page location is irrelevant in the resolution of a relative URL) in the parent folder. You should replace references like that with an absolute reference, e.g.

```
<link href="/css/Style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working i Will Mark As Answer after 5 min and sorry for simple question am new in asp.net

Comment: No problem, it's an easy mistake to make, even with experience :)

Comment: http://localhost/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Probably a different issue worthy of a new question to get the right experts' opinions. However, does the file exist? If not you probably need to get hold of it and put it in the right place.